# slideside menu doesn't hide when click on another slideside menu or dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a menu similar to the Dropdown menu of bootstrap, the minor difference is, it doesn't slide down, instead, it slides left side on click and this is working fine. But the issue is I want that it must be closed when clicked on another menu(slideside or dropdown) but it is not working when I try to click on another menu link( which is not child or parent of the same slideside menu). It doesn't disappear as dropdown menu disappears when clicked on another menu.However, if I clicked outside anywhere on the window it closes the menu. Take a look at my code which I have taken from bootstrap plugin.
I have used the bootstrap `clearMenus` function to close the menus and edited however it doesn't resolve my problem. As I snippet you will see if I clicked on both category button they will overlap and I want if I click on another category then it must close the other open cateogry.

```js
var toggle   = '[data-toggle="slideside"]'
     var Slideside = function (element) {
    $(element).on('click', this.toggle)
     }
function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')
    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }
    var $parent = selector && $(selector)
    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
   }
   $(".slideside-toggle").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var expand ;
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = getParent($this);
    $slide = $this.next('ul').children('.after-slideside');
    if($this.attr('aria-expanded') === 'true')
     expand = 'false'; 
    else
     expand = 'true';
    
    $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    $slide.toggleClass("open");
   });
   $(document).on('click',clearMenus);
   function clearMenus(e){
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      var $this         = $(this)
      var $parent       = getParent($this)
      var $slide   = $this.next('ul').children('.after-slideside');
      if (!$slide.hasClass('open')) return
      if (e && e.type == 'click' && /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName) && $.contains($parent[0], e.target)) return
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
      $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      $slide.removeClass('open')
    })
   }
```

```css
.slideside-toggle i.fa-angle-right{
    padding-right:0;
   }
   li.after-slideside{
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:ghostwhite;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside > a{
    padding-left:8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
    color:#acacac;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside >ul{
    padding-left:0;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside >ul>li{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
   }
   .open.after-slideside{
    right:0;
    transition:all 0.35s linear;
    z-index:1;
   }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.hetrotech.in/css/color.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
   <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sliders"></i> Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Not Logged In ?</li>
            <li class="button"><button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.location.href='user.html';"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in"></i>Login</button></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="before-slideside" id="category">
         <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>Category 1 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
         <ul class="slideside-menu">
            <li class="after-slideside">
               <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">20% Sale</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false">Product2 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                     <ul class="slideside-menu">
                        <li class="after-slideside">
                           <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-header">40% Sale</li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="before-slideside" id="category">
         <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>Category 1 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
         <ul class="slideside-menu">
            <li class="after-slideside">
               <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">20% Sale</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false">Product2 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                     <ul class="slideside-menu">
                        <li class="after-slideside">
                           <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-header">40% Sale</li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove class **open** to .after-slideside and .dropdown in slideside-toggle click event

```js
var toggle   = '[data-toggle="slideside"]'
     var Slideside = function (element) {
    $(element).on('click', this.toggle)
     }
function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')
    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }
    var $parent = selector && $(selector)
    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
   }
   $(".slideside-toggle").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var expand ;
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = getParent($this);
$parent.siblings().find('.after-slideside, .dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $slide = $this.next('ul').children('.after-slideside');
    if($this.attr('aria-expanded') === 'true')
     expand = 'false'; 
    else
     expand = 'true';
    
    $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    $slide.toggleClass("open");
   });
   $(".dropdown").on('click',function(e){
$(this).siblings().find('.after-slideside, .dropdown').removeClass('open');
    
   });
   $(document).on('click',clearMenus);
   function clearMenus(e){
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      var $this         = $(this)
      var $parent       = getParent($this)
      var $slide   = $this.next('ul').children('.after-slideside');
      if (!$slide.hasClass('open')) return
      if (e && e.type == 'click' && /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName) && $.contains($parent[0], e.target)) return
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
      $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      $slide.removeClass('open')
    })
   }
```

```css
.slideside-toggle i.fa-angle-right{
    padding-right:0;
   }
   li.after-slideside{
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:ghostwhite;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside > a{
    padding-left:8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
    color:#acacac;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside >ul{
    padding-left:0;
   }
   nav li.open.after-slideside >ul>li{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
   }
   .open.after-slideside{
    right:0;
    transition:all 0.35s linear;
    z-index:1;
   }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.hetrotech.in/css/color.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
   <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sliders"></i> Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Not Logged In ?</li>
            <li class="button"><button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.location.href='user.html';"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in"></i>Login</button></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="before-slideside" id="category">
         <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>Category 1 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
         <ul class="slideside-menu">
            <li class="after-slideside">
               <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">20% Sale</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false">Product2 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                     <ul class="slideside-menu">
                        <li class="after-slideside">
                           <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-header">40% Sale</li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="before-slideside" id="category">
         <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>Category 1 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
         <ul class="slideside-menu">
            <li class="after-slideside">
               <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">20% Sale</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#" class="slideside-toggle" data-toggle="slideside" aria-expanded="false">Product2 <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                     <ul class="slideside-menu">
                        <li class="after-slideside">
                           <ul class="slideside-menu" role="menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-header">40% Sale</li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: okay that's nice, half of my problem has been solved, but the problem remains is that if I click on dropdown menu then it doesn't hide.